# InfoPath 2010 People Picker is not working in Local Machine but in server

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have a people picker control in infopath 2010 form, which is working fine in staging server.But, not in local machine. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding *multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"* in the web.config file for the web application.

The default path of the web.config file is: *c:\Inetpub\Wwwroot\WSS\VirtualDirectories*.

Find:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Change it to:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=”true” multipleSiteBindingsEnabled=”true” />
 </system.serviceModel>
```

A similar issue:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d6fa5812-64e0-4d80-94b0-0577ba43ce59/sharepoint-2013-infopath-2010-people-picker-does-not-works-when-opens-in-client-application-but?forum=sharepointcustomization